# IDP failing on test page

Tags: debugging, simplesamlphp

I have installed a simplesamlphp instance, and set it up for facebook login with success on the mysite.org/simplesaml interface.

I was wanting to get linkedin and twitter configured too. I followed the instructions for creating an app on the 3rd party site, and have triple checked my settings with regard to the keys and secrets on authsources.php. I have created an *enable* file in the relevant module directories.

When I test the authentication source, I get redirected to a blank page with, for example *simplesaml/module.php/core/authenticate.php?as=linkedin* as an address.

How can I troubleshoot this? I can not find any logs, and no error messages appear on the page. I have enabled showerrors and debug of saml and backtraces in the *config/templates/config.php*

I have tried disabling the facebook login (which still works fine) incase it was a problem with more than one module active at a time, but this did not help.

Comment: I've just discovered how to enable logging (_config/config.php_). I'll report back if I find a solution

Comment: So, I'm getting a _SimpleSAML_Error_Exception: Error 1 - Class sspmod_oauth_Consumer not found_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SSP can't find a `sspmod_*` class than either that module is not installed or not enabled. Based on the class name `sspmod_oauth_Consumer` I know it is looking in the `modules/oauth` folder, and I know the `oauth` module is include (but not enabled) by default.

To enable the module you can do `touch modules/oauth/enable`